# Issue with table nth-child after add grid-gap

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently our table:
[image]

First have background and second is white - is correct.

now I would like to move the attributes to the right. I add to table code:

```
.table-wrapper tbody {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 0 24px;
}
```

Now is result:
[image]

But is issue. I need result somelike this:
[image]

Can anyone help me correct our code?

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("tr:odd").css({
    "background-color":"#000",
    "color":"black"});
});
```

```css
.additional-attributes tr th {
    border-right: 0px solid #ccc;
    font-weight: 200;
    width: 0%;
}
additional-attributes tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
additional-attributes tr {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc !important;
}
.table-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.additional-attributes tr td {
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #f8fafb;
  color: black;
}
.table-wrapper tbody {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 0 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
        <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

update code:

```
<style>
.seller-attributes {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
.additional-attributes tr th {
    border-right: 0px solid #ccc;
    font-weight: 200;
    width: 0%;
}
additional-attributes tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
additional-attributes tr {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc !important;
}
.table-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.additional-attributes tr td {
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #f8fafb;
  color: black;
}

/* ADDED */
tbody tr:nth-of-type(4n + 3), tbody tr:nth-of-type(4n){
  background-color: white;
}
tbody tr:(even){
  padding-left: 24px;
}
.additional-attributes tbody tr {
        display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}
.additional-attributes tr th {
    width: 100%
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why are you using `display: grid;` on `<tbody>`? why even use a table if you're going to do that?

Comment: Looks like you just need 2 `<ul>`

Comment: Our table is generated automatically by php  foreach https://prnt.sc/12h620l

Comment: If you have write access to this PHP code and you can change, I suggest changing it instead if hacking an HTML table

Comment: @T J it is possible get answear from you with implement this 2 <ul> ?

Comment: Can you tell us how we can do it directly in the php code?

Comment: Please make an attempt to create the HTML structure with `<ul>`, if you have trouble styling it like this ask a question and I'll be glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this css to make the background correctly, you dont need jQuery:

```css
/* ADDED */
tbody tr:nth-of-type(4n + 3), tbody tr:nth-of-type(4n){
  background-color: salmon;
}
tbody tr:nth-of-type(4n - 3), tbody tr:nth-of-type(4n -2){
  background-color: grey;
}
tbody tr:(even){
  padding-left: 24px;
}
.additional-attributes tbody tr{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}
.additional-attributes tr th{
  width: 100%;
  text-align:right;
}
.additional-attributes tr td{
  text-align:left;
}
```

### DEMO:

```js
/*$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("tr:odd").css({
    "background-color":"#000",
    "color":"black"});
});*/
```

```css
.additional-attributes tr th {
    border-right: 0px solid #ccc;
    font-weight: 200;
    width: 0%;
}
.additional-attributes tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
.additional-attributes tr {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc !important;
}
.table-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.additional-attributes tr td {
  font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0 10px; 
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #f8fafb;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.table-wrapper tbody {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    /*grid-gap: 0 24px;*/
}
/* ADDED */
tbody tr:nth-of-type(4n + 3), tbody tr:nth-of-type(4n){
  background-color: salmon;
}
tbody tr:nth-of-type(4n - 3), tbody tr:nth-of-type(4n -2){
  background-color: grey;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  padding-left: 24px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.additional-attributes tbody tr{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}
.additional-attributes tr th{
  width: 100%;
  text-align:right;
}
.additional-attributes tr td{
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
        <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr I am longer</th>
                    <td class="data">first I am longer</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                    <td class="data">first</td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Great! We've almost achieved this effect. But it still doesn't color the attributes that are transferred to the right with the grid function.

Comment: do you have free time to check this for us ? Then we accept your answear. Thanks! https://prnt.sc/12hotnu

Comment: Based on the image you sent, I cannot tell. But it might be a problem of css priority, if does not apply as the demo I sent you

Comment: maybe issue for you to check on live page? https://feerdi.pl/orient-triton-automatic-ra-ac0k04e10b-mens-watch-ra-ac0k04e10b.html

Comment: If you set `display: grid; grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;` on your `.additional-attributes tbody tr` it should already fix your alignment problem. And add `width: 100%;` to `.additional-attributes tr th`

Comment: @MaxuGui I update my full CSS code in topic after this changes. But currently I get result  https://prnt.sc/12il41h

Comment: please check demo

Comment: @TomArm based on your live website, it seems to work fine, just replace the salmon color by the color you would like

Comment: We almost git this effect: But currently after update demo is https://prnt.sc/12in03u and we try get some like this https://prnt.sc/12imxsk

Comment: Check demo, I just added: `tbody tr:nth-child(odd){  margin-right: 5px; }` & `tbody tr:nth-child(even){  margin-left: 5px; }`

Comment: ohhh great! Thanks for your persistence and help!

Answer (score 1):

You want to divide the `tr`s into 2 parts

So it is better to have 2 parts

I put 2 `tbody` so that it can be divided into 2 parts and changed the `.table-wrapper tbody` to `.table-wrapper` table to put 2 `tbody` in 2 separate parts

It is better to put your code in different sections so that it is more readable and does not cause any interference

Adding `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;` to `tbody` prevented the colors of `tr`s from being transferred to other sections

Of course, this is in fact the case
You can find out by putting a difference in the `odd` or `even` `tr`s

But the point is that when you use `odd`, you are actually going to divide `tr` into 2 parts: `odd` and `even`

Also, when you use `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;`, `tr`s are supposed to be divided into 2 parts.

As a result of this disorder

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("tr:odd").css({"background-color":"#000","color":"black"});
});
```

```css
.additional-attributes tr th {
    border-right: 0px solid #ccc;
    font-weight: 200;
    width: 0%;
}

additional-attributes tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}

additional-attributes tr {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc !important;
}

.table-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.additional-attributes tr td {
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f8fafb;
    color: black;
}

.table-wrapper table {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 0 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
    <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                <td class="data">first</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                <td class="data">first</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                <td class="data">first</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                <td class="data">first</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                <td class="data">first</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                <td class="data">first</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                <td class="data">first</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                <td class="data">first</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Parametr</th>
                <td class="data">first</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I was writing an explanation
I also added an explanation

Comment: Posting code without answer is not a good pratice: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: Based your code, comment the jQuery and add css: `tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n + 2){background-color: black;}` That will fit with his requirement of background